# Is this variant of a worker queue some sort of pattern or common structure?

Tags: c++, boost

I am wondering if the following concept is known as a programming pattern.

Imagine a worker queue, but instead of each queue entry beeing removed when processed, it should be removed when another thread has catched the remove-event or when a remove-event was triggered.

So it would go like this:

- command gets into the queue
- 2nd command gets into the queue
- 3rd ...
- first command gets processed
- first command waits to be removed
- 2nd command gets processed
- remove-event for first command was fired
- first command gets removed
- 2nd command waits to be removed
- ...

I hope, I made this clear enough to understand.

Now is there a boost library, which has implemented such behaviour? Is there a pattern representing this behaviour?

Comment: seems very complicated, why not removing the command right away? What's the purpose?

Comment: the purpose is, the command has to be confirmed. Each command will result in a corresponding response. However, I want to process the other command, until this response arrives or a timeout "reactivates" the command to be resent.

Comment: How do you prevent a command to be assigned twice?

Comment: Ah, yeah, though about using some indicator-field, like an 2d-array, having the command and the state - but Tony's idea seems to be a better attempt.

Comment: I had the impression you wanted to have a single queue, and it felt a bit complicated to handle. Indeed, Tony's idea is easier to implement, and faster. If you want to go multithreaded, it's also the better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, you're just talking about two queues - the "novel" one being the queue of pending removals.  Standard queues (deque) should be fine.  You'd need a mutex, and a condition variable to signal the removal events.  Wanting a name for such a pattern is a bit gradiose (people expect that too much these days)... if I were describing it I might say we have a decoupled removal thread (assuming that's how you implement it), an asynchronous removal process (similarly), or even delayed element removal (which is true even if not done in a separate thread).

Comment: thanks for this - it confirms my gut feeling, but eversince I am using boost and looking out for design patterns, I overcomplicate things. I will experiment with that and should nothing better come along, this will be it.